# Replace All Commas with Blank in an Array

Tags: google-apps-script

I have hit a dead end - need some help!  code is below.  Should be very simple.... I have an array that is many rows long and 33 columns wide..... I just need to get all the commas out of the array values.  The array is composed of some string fields and also some number fields.....  Any help is appreciated!

So far I can't get any luck with the .replace function.... thanks

```
function Pipeline() {
  var writelocation = SpreadsheetApp.openById(globalvariables().importerid);
  var writesheet = writelocation.getSheetByName("Pipeline");
  var linkssheet = writelocation.getSheetByName(globalvariables().linkstab);
  writesheet.getRange("A:AG").clear();
  //var length = 1 + getLastRowSpecial(linkssheet.getRange("C:C").getValues());
  var length = 5;
  var array = [];
  var array = [
    ["Highlight", "Customer", "Prospect", "Type", "Status", "Product Detail & Comments", "Start Date", "End Date", "Bulk Sales", "Bulk GM%", "Non-Bulk Sales", "Non-Bulk GM%", "Safety Sales", "Safety GM%", "Welding Sales", "Welding GM%", "Rent / Other Sales", "Rent / Other GM%", "Source", "Segment", "Competitor", "Contract Expiration", "Win Reason", "Loss Reason", "PSA Won", "Contacts", "Probability", "Monthly Sales", "Monthly GM", "12M Sales", "District", "Area", "Salesperson"]
    ];    
  for (i=2; i<length; i++) {
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(linkssheet.getRange(i,3).getValue()).getSheetByName("Pipeline").getRange("A4:AG").getValues().filter(function(item){ return item[4] != ""; });

    for (k=0; k<source.length; k++) {
      for (j=0; j<source[k].length; j++) {
        source[k][j].toString().replace(/[,]/g,'-');  

      } 
      array.push(source[k]);
         }
  }
  writesheet.getRange(1,1,array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);  
  linkssheet.getRange("E3").setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script has multiple issue-

1. You are declaring same variable twice-

`var array = [];
 var array = ["Highlight",...]`

2. You are setting header values in a 1D array, which can not be written to Sheet.

`var array = [
    ["Highlight", "Customer", "Prospect", "Type", "Status", "Product Detail & Comments", "Start Date", "End Date", "Bulk Sales", "Bulk GM%", "Non-Bulk Sales", "Non-Bulk GM%", "Safety Sales", "Safety GM%", "Welding Sales", "Welding GM%", "Rent / Other Sales", "Rent / Other GM%", "Source", "Segment", "Competitor", "Contract Expiration", "Win Reason", "Loss Reason", "PSA Won", "Contacts", "Probability", "Monthly Sales", "Monthly GM", "12M Sales", "District", "Area", "Salesperson"]
    ];`

3. You are replacing "," with "-" when the title say you want to replace it with space
4. You are not assigning the replaced value to any other variable, the replace method doesn't changes the object it is called on.

So this is how your code should look like

```
function Pipeline() {
  var writelocation = SpreadsheetApp.openById(globalvariables().importerid);
  var writesheet = writelocation.getSheetByName("Pipeline");
  var linkssheet = writelocation.getSheetByName(globalvariables().linkstab);
  writesheet.getRange("A:AG").clear();
  //var length = 1 + getLastRowSpecial(linkssheet.getRange("C:C").getValues());
  var length = 5;
  var array = [];
  array[0] = [
    ["Highlight", "Customer", "Prospect", "Type", "Status", "Product Detail & Comments", "Start Date", "End Date", "Bulk Sales", "Bulk GM%", "Non-Bulk Sales", "Non-Bulk GM%", "Safety Sales", "Safety GM%", "Welding Sales", "Welding GM%", "Rent / Other Sales", "Rent / Other GM%", "Source", "Segment", "Competitor", "Contract Expiration", "Win Reason", "Loss Reason", "PSA Won", "Contacts", "Probability", "Monthly Sales", "Monthly GM", "12M Sales", "District", "Area", "Salesperson"]
  ];    
  for (i=2; i<length; i++) {
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(linkssheet.getRange(i,3).getValue()).getSheetByName("Pipeline").getRange("A4:AG").getValues().filter(function(item){ return item[4] != ""; });

    for (k=0; k<source.length; k++) {
      for (j=0; j<source[k].length; j++) {
        source[k][j] = source[k][j].toString().replace(/[,]/g,' ');  

      } 
      array.push(source[k]);
    }
  }
  writesheet.getRange(1,1,array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);  
  linkssheet.getRange("E3").setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution solved the problem, specifically with processing the array correctly.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that `source[k][j].toString().replace(/[,]/g,'-');` is required to be put to `source[k][j]`.

  - I think that the reason of your issue might be this.
- Your title is `Replace All Commas with Blank in an Array`. But, `replace(/[,]/g,'-')` replaces `,` to `-`. Although I'm not sure about the actual value of `source[k][j].toString()`, if you want to replace `,` to blank, please modify to `replace(/[,]/g,' ')` or `replace(/[,]/g,'')`.

  - I think that you want to replace only `,`, you can also use `replace(/,/g,' ')`

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
source[k][j].toString().replace(/[,]/g,'-');
```

To:

```
source[k][j] = source[k][j].toString().replace(/[,]/g,' ');  // or replace(/[,]/g,'')
```

#### Reference:

- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

```
function Pipeline() {
  var writelocation = SpreadsheetApp.openById(globalvariables().importerid);
  var writesheet = writelocation.getSheetByName("Pipeline");
  var linkssheet = writelocation.getSheetByName(globalvariables().linkstab);
  writesheet.getRange(1,1,writesheet.getLastRow(),33).clear();
  var array = [["Highlight", "Customer", "Prospect", "Type", "Status", "Product Detail & Comments", "Start Date", "End Date", "Bulk Sales", "Bulk GM%", "Non-Bulk Sales", "Non-Bulk GM%", "Safety Sales", "Safety GM%", "Welding Sales", "Welding GM%", "Rent / Other Sales", "Rent / Other GM%", "Source", "Segment", "Competitor", "Contract Expiration", "Win Reason", "Loss Reason", "PSA Won", "Contacts", "Probability", "Monthly Sales", "Monthly GM", "12M Sales", "District", "Area", "Salesperson"]];    
  var vs=linksheet.getRange(2,3,3,1).getValues();
  vs.forEach(function(url,i){
    var sss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ssh=sss.getSheetByName("Pipeline");
    var srg=ssh.getRange(4,1,ssh.getLastRow()-3,1);
    var source=srg.getValues();
    source.forEach(function(r,k){
      r.forEach(function(c,j){
        source[k][j].replace(/[,]/g,'');
      });
      array.push(source[k])
    });   
    writesheet.getRange(1,1,array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);  
    linkssheet.getRange("E3").setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  });
}
```